# Setting retina background images appear zoomed in

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm setting a random background image for my app by loading an image and adding it to my view:

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                               initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg%u.jpg", 1+arc4random_uniform(15)]]];
    [self.view addSubview:background];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:background];
```

My images are 640x1136 at 326 ppi, yet the image is appearing zoomed in for some reason. Any ideas as to why would be appreciated.

Simulator

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU38H.png]

Actual image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIm9F.png]

Thanks.

Comment: Try with png file instead. It might be conversion issue

Comment: @Nick background.frame = self.view.frame; then addSubView:

Comment: @b3ginneriOS converting to a png didn't appear to work at all unfortunately.

Comment: @Spynet this worked perfectly. Thank you! can you add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Nick welcome keep asking questions

Comment: @Nick how you are naming retina and non retina images. Non-retina image should follow convention like "imageName.png " and retina image should follow convention like  "imageName@2x.png " . If you does like this iOS itself picks image based on device resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It s because you alloc init with your image, not with a fix size.

```
int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
int screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;


UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];

background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg%u.jpg",1+arc4random_uniform(15)]]

[self.view addSubview:background];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:background];
```

Do it like this

Comment: what is screenWidth and screenHeight ?

Comment: changed answer to this based on the assumption that you're correct about downsampling, though the images look the same on the iphone screen (maybe it's too small to see). It works after your edits. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is not from me, and this solution is not any different than that of spynet! In fact, i think i might have been wrong (i was testing a couple of things)

Comment: I don't see a solution from you at all, just comments that none of them are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try like this,

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                               initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg%u.jpg", 1+arc4random_uniform(15)]]];

    background.frame = self.view.frame; // this is the only line you have missed 
    [self.view addSubview:background];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:background];
```

Comment: This is not the right solution. The image will be downsampled and it will look just like what it would look on a non-retina phone.

Comment: i'm testing this on an iPhone5 and the images appear high resolution, any ideas?

Comment: I don't know about downsample( or Spynet code is not good ), but I know that, my answer is correct.

Comment: @micantox what is downsampled ?